# Error on line of request dispatcher on void doget()?

Tags: java, servlets

Why my request dispatcher is not working? Are there any internal mistakes? Is my if statement correct?

```
if(password.equals("arjun"))
{       
    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
}
else
{
    out.println("<p> wrong password enterd</p>");
    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp"));
    rd.include(request, response);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Any error you're getting? If yes, tell us the error and line you're getting that error.

Comment: And if you are getting an exception, please post the entire stack trace into the question as well.  Makes finding errors much much easier for us.

Comment: In both case you are redirecting to `index.jsp` , you might want to change that !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the code it might help you:

```
import java.io.*;  
import javax.servlet.*;  
import javax.servlet.http.*;  


public class Login extends HttpServlet {  

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
        throws ServletException, IOException {  

    response.setContentType("text/html");  
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  

    String n=request.getParameter("userName");  
    String p=request.getParameter("userPass");  

    if(p.equals("servlet"){  
        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("servlet2");  
        rd.forward(request, response);  
    }  
    else{  
        out.print("Sorry UserName or Password Error!");  
        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");  
        rd.include(request, response);  

        }  
    }  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think your code is ok if your uri for "index.jsp" is valid.

```
    if(password.equals("arjun"))
    {       /*index.jsp is relative path*/
        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
    else
    {
        out.println("<p> wrong password enterd</p>");
        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp"));
        rd.include(request, response);
    }
```

if your "index.jsp" page exist in root folder change your url as "/index.jsp"

```
if(password.equals("arjun"))
{       /* "/index.jsp" is absolute path*/
    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
}
else
{
    out.println("<p> wrong password enterd</p>");
    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp"));
    rd.include(request, response);
}
```